# PySide: Connecting QComboBox indices with QWidgets

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

I would like to connect my QComboBox indices with opening new widgets. I would like to do this so, that when another QComboBox index is selected, the previously opened widget is closed. Now the widgets are only adding up one after another.

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
import pandas as pd
import pyqtgraph as pg


class Widget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        v_global_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()

        method_selection = QtGui.QComboBox()
        method_selection.addItem("A")
        method_selection.addItem("B")

        v_global_layout.addWidget(method_selection)
        v_global_layout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)

        def change_widget(index):
            a = Graph()
            b = TabDialog()

            if index == 0:
                v_global_layout.addWidget(a)
            elif index == 1:
                v_global_layout.addWidget(b)

        method_selection.activated.connect(change_widget)

        self.setLayout(v_global_layout)

class TabDialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        tab_widget = QtGui.QTabWidget()
        tab_widget.addTab(QtGui.QWidget(), "1")
        tab_widget.addTab(QtGui.QWidget(), "2")

        main_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(tab_widget)
        self.setLayout(main_layout)


class Graph(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.fig = pg.PlotWidget(name='PlotWidget')
        self.plot_area = self.fig.plotItem

        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.fig)
        self.setLayout(layout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    main_window = Widget()
    main_window.setGeometry(100, 100, 640, 480)
    main_window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You can use QStackedWidget and change currentIndex When comboBox change or this is not what you want?

Comment: I wrote my comment to clarify task. Now I can write this as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest you better way.

There is special widget [QStackedWidget](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qstackedwidget.html). You can add different widgets and use [activated](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qcombobox.html#activated) signal from `QComboBox`. Also you can use [setCurrentIndex](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qstackedwidget.html#setCurrentIndex) to change widgets.

Comment: I posted my solution below.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to my problem is to use QStackedWidget.

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
import pandas as pd
import pyqtgraph as pg


class Widget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        v_global_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()

        method_selection = QtGui.QComboBox()
        method_selection.addItem("A")
        method_selection.addItem("B")

        self.stackedWidget = QtGui.QStackedWidget()
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(TabDialog())
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(Graph())

        method_selection.activated[int].connect(self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex)

        v_global_layout.addWidget(method_selection)
        v_global_layout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        v_global_layout.addWidget(self.stackedWidget)
        self.setLayout(v_global_layout)

class TabDialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        tab_widget = QtGui.QTabWidget()
        tab_widget.addTab(QtGui.QWidget(), "1")
        tab_widget.addTab(QtGui.QWidget(), "2")

        main_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(tab_widget)
        self.setLayout(main_layout)


class Graph(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.fig = pg.PlotWidget(name='PlotWidget')
        self.plot_area = self.fig.plotItem

        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.fig)
        self.setLayout(layout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    main_window = Widget()
    main_window.setGeometry(100, 100, 640, 480)
    main_window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```